# Clearing Contents of Row with For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have code that is designed to loop through each cell in a row and delete them EXCEPT for the A and O columns. When I run this code it only deletes the second column.

I am aware of the "Rows(Target.Row).ClearContents" line but this does not suit my purposes as I need specific columns to stay intact.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To i = 30
    If i = 15 Then
        'update i but do nothing
        i = i + 1
    Else
        'update i and clear contents of cell
        .Cells(Target.Row, i).Clear
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The For loop increments the i so you shouldn't, and this syntax is incorrect `For i = 2 To i = 30`:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 30
    If i <> 15 Then .Cells(Target.Row, i).Clear
Next
```

A faster way to exclude certain columns from the row (without using a loop):

```
With Target.Parent
    .Columns(15).Hidden = True
    .UsedRange.Rows(Target.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
    .Columns(15).Hidden = False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that for loops automatically increment in VBA. I'm so used to doing it manually in C++. As soon as it lets me accept your answer I will. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why use loops at all?

```
Union(Range(.Cells(Target.Row,2),.Cells(Target.Row,14)), Range(.Cells(Target.Row,16),.Cells(Target.Row,30))).Clear
```

Comment: And the address version: `Range("B" & target.Row & ":N" & target.Row & ",P" & target.Row & ":AD" & target.Row & "").ClearContents` Same thing (hence why I commented rather than answering) just slightly easier to understand when skimming through the code.

Comment: Interesting way of going about it. I guess I just use loops because they are easier for me to think about but this should definitely work too. I do have to say that it is not friendly to read this line of code whereas the loop is much cleaner.